# i want to when i add start date the end date automatically comes using flutter

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart

SizedBox(
//   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
child: TextFormField(
//  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
//FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
// inputFormatters: [
//   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
//       RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
//   LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
// ],
controller: startdatecntr,
keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
decoration: const InputDecoration(
errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
border: OutlineInputBorder(),
hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize: 12,
),
labelText: 'Start Date',
hintText: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
),
onTap: () async {
DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
context: context,
initialDate: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(
1991), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
lastDate: DateTime(2101),
// onConfirm:widget.onChanged,
).then((pickedDate) {
if (pickedDate != null) {
// print(
// pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
String formattedDate =
DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
.format(pickedDate);

```
                                  print(formattedDate);

                                  setState(() {
                                    startdatecntr.text = formattedDate;
                                    //set output date to TextField value.
                                  });
                                  print(startdatecntr.text);
                                } else {
                                  print("Date is not selected");
                                }
                              });
                            },

                            validator: MultiValidator([
                              RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')
                            ]),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 13,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            // maxLength: 8,
                            // autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                            autofocus: false,
                            controller: enddatecntr,
                            // inputFormatters: [
                            //   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            //       RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                            //   LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                            // ],
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                                counterText: "",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                                labelText: 'End Date',
                                hintText: ' yyyy-MM-dd'),
                            onTap: () async {
                              DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                context: context,
                                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                firstDate: DateTime(
                                    1991), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                                lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                                // onConfirm:widget.onChanged,
                              ).then((pickedDate) {
                                if (pickedDate != null) {
                                  // print(
                                  // pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                                  String formattedDate =
                                      DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                          .format(pickedDate);

                                  print(formattedDate);

                                  setState(() {
                                    enddatecntr.text = formattedDate;
                                    //set output date to TextField value.
                                  });
                                  print(enddatecntr.text);
                                } else {
                                  print("Date is not selected");
                                }
                              });
                            },
```

Comment: Try ```DateTime.now()```

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
return Text(
 DateTime.now().toString(),
 );
```

Comment: i want to when i select start date the end date automatically comes using months like 12, 24, 36, 48  in flutter flutter